# Devemos ter mais opções para classificar as postagens?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Tenho dúvidas para a SE e para a comunidade.

Podemos ter mais opções de *notice* como a usada em alguns sites da rede? [Vide Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302609/140010).

Devemos começar usar mais esses alertas em perguntas e respostas para até evitar negativação, remoção, etc.?

Mais ainda, seria o caso de voltarmos usar Community Wiki em *posts* que não são exatamente respostas como costumamos classificar ou que não sejam perguntas que vão gerar essas respostas , mas que podem ser úteis, como *poll questions*, listas, por exemplo?

A comunidade deveria pelo menos poder iniciar ou mesmo fazer certas ações independente de moderadores diamante? Um exemplo seria transforma resposta em comentário (muitos *posts* acabam sendo removidos quando poderia servir de alguma forma). Muitas coisas precisam ser feitas rapidamente, e causa menos dano ter que desfazer depois, se foi equivocado.

Isto vai de encontro ao [recente post no blog da rede](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) que pretende fazer a rede ser mais inclusiva, o que eu acho bom, mas precisamos de métodos e ferramentas adequados para lidar com isto. Espero que o discurso de ouvir com mente aberta desta vez seja real, até porque é a última que eu acredito nisto.

Farei novos *posts* sugerindo melhorias, faça você também. Nem todos são viáveis ou desejáveis. Se realmente quiserem melhorar não procurarão só os problemas da proposta, mas o que pode ser feito um pouco diferente para obter um bom resultado a *feature* sair do papel, até porque algo mais ou menos útil é melhor que algo útil que não existe ou algo que existe mas está atrapalhando.

Para quem não sabe, moderadores podem marcar *posts* como "especiais" e em algumas comunidades é muito usado:

[image: Avisos de pubblicação]

[image: Mensagens de bloqueio]

Não temos aqui, mas poderíamos ter algo como, mas não exatamente o mesmo: [perguntas da semana](https://superuser.com/q/486788/20555) e [perguntas que são FAQ](https://superuser.com/q/100360/20555) (tem até uma [*tag*  considerada meta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq)) .

---

O criador "se voltando contra" a criatura :) (por favor não entendam errado)

https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/989634067338440704
https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/991459798745956352
https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/991082088689381376

Concordo com isso, mas precisa das ferramentas adequadas para funcionar bem, hoje nem o SO, nem o Quora as possuem.

Comment: Tem umas coisas relativamente simples que já ajudariam bastante, e nem precisaria ser realtime. Exemplo: um batch que avisasse os negativadores de todas as negativadas que foram editadas depois, para possível reconsideração

Comment: Outra coisa é a bendita da busca, que é muito engessada. Tem muita duplicata que acaba passando, com ótimas respostas já dadas anos antes, pelo simples fato de não serem fáceis de achar (por exemplo, fazendo a busca pelo thread todo, não só pela pergunta OU resposta) - E o problema da duplicata não é ter conteúdo "em dobro", e sim o fato de que quanto mais demora pra fechar, mais tem chance de resposta ruim negativada, ou de respostas boas "divididas" entre posts.

Comment: E eu tb já disse muitas vezes: o simples "refrasear" das mensagens de fechamento já mudaria o "tom" do site completamente, com mensagens no estilo: explicar que (quando aplicável) o fechamento é temporário > dizer o que tem de errado > explicar porque precisa fechar até resolver > como resolver de fato. Hoje é muito "sua questão tem problema. arrume!"

Comment: Agora, uma observação: se for pra fazer muita "assistência social", também não adianta. Queira quer não, o fato de "be welcome" não ter sido prioridade foi o que fez o site funcionar muito bem até hoje (não digo que não possa ser "welcomeável", mas nao pode ser a prioridade). Se for pra mexer nos pilares, melhor fazer um site à parte e provar que ficou melhor, em vez de estragar o que funciona.

Comment: Sempre achei que seria desejável haver mais "opções de *notice*" disponíveis para "utilizadores comuns" de forma a proporcionar uma classificação mais fina de eventuais problemas com perguntas/respostas. Por vezes abstenho-me de votar por dificuldade de classificação. Agora que tive conhecimento das possibilidades existentes para os moderadores e vejo que praticamente não são usadas me leva a crer que há pouca participação/actuação (de alguns) dos moderadores. A transformação de respostas em comentário era algo que eu via ser feito com alguma frequência mas ultimamente não.

Comment: @Bacco assino em baixo de tudo o que disse. Alguns ficarão bravos com o que vou dizer, mas até onde eu sei o iniciante, aqui no SOpt, raramente é mal recebido. O usuário iniciante ou experiente que é dumb/lazy/stuborn (provavelmente a soma dos 3) tem dificuldades mesmo. E não sei se deve mudar muito. Aceitar mais conteúdos, classificar melhor, lidar mais facilmente com os problemas é algo desejável. E vou falar o que falo há 4 anos, a ferramenta precisa evoluir para ser melhor para todos, até para o snowflake que citei agora.  Qualidade e diversidade podem andar juntos, só não é simples.

Comment: @ramaral Eu ando com menos tempo e na verdade tem tanto para fazer que o correto é deixar a comunidade fazer a maioria das coisas, deixar para moderadores só o que foi feito errado, o que envolve alguma privacidade e coisas que gerarão maior repercussão. Acho que a comunidade, deve ter mais poder de moderação, agira rápido. Se for bem explicado, se puder reverter fácil, se só puder quem se mostra confiável (não pode ser baseado só em reputação), fica muito melhor, atende e demanda de muitos. Eu acho que pode até acabar os downvotes e os closes se a ferramenta for adequada.

Comment: Concordo com tudo.                                                                     *"(...)  se só puder quem se mostra confiável (não pode ser baseado só em reputação),(...)"* - A reputação na tag poderia ser um factor diferenciador.

Comment: @ramaral sem dúvida, **na *tag***, mas também precisa de algo mais subjetivo, a SE preza exageradamente os números, erro que grande parte das *startups* estão cometendo.

Comment: Acredito que as métricas tem que ser números mesmo. Critérios subjetivos são difíceis de definir claramente e difíceis de medir, além de ser comumente parciais. Acho que o problema não são os números, mas sim o fato de serem analisados de modo isolado. Atrabés da atividade no próprio site é possível traçar um perfil do usuário que poderia indicar uma confiabilidade. Por exemplo, esse indicador de perfil poderia usar uma combinação entre limites como 'perguntadores' vs 'respondendores', posts positivos vs posts negativos, participação construtiva vs participação consumista... e por aí vai

Comment: Não se mede critérios subjetivos. Nós não somos robôs. Achar que números dizem tudo engessa qualquer coisa, e achar que números não metem é muito ingênuo. Números confessam tudo o que você quer. Para tratar os números de forma global é próximo do impossível, mesmo se colocar IA terá que treinar, o que estamos longe de conseguir fazê-lo, e se conseguir, ou não valerá o esforço ou a IA chegou no nível que o Musk teme. O site não consegue fazer por conta própria até as coisas fáceis objetivas, quanto mais coletar informações e tratar as subjetivas difíceis.  Citou um monte de coisa subjetiva.

Comment: Se _não se mede_ então nem deveria ser critério - seria a pura opinião. O ponto não é achar que números dizem tudo, mas tentar extrair o máximo de informações (mesmo que tendências) a partir deles. Sim, os parâmetros que iriam compor cada idicador precisariam estar abertos para colocar em pauta a qualquer momento. Se o número _estiver confessando o que a comunidade quer saber_, entendo que seria um resultado positivo. Senão, de fato os seus parâmetros deveriam ser reavaliados em um ciclo virtuoso. Nem me referi a IA, acho que não valeria mesmo o esforço. E esse realmente não deve ser o foco.

Comment: O que citei seriam indicadores baseados em critérios objetivos. Números mesmo. Não os vejo de outra forma. Mas entrar em entrar em detalhes estaria desviando o foco desta thread. Não que números não mintam, muito longe disso. Mas números tendem a ser muito menos parciais do que "critérios subjetivos". A influência de uns certamente afetaria o "julgamento subjetivo" de outros.

Comment: A ideia do @Bacco de notificar os negativadores como uma ação efetiva para conotar a receptividade da comunidade é excelente e muito útil.

Comment: Por isso eu prefiro uma abordagem humanista, só precisa de humanos com a "cabeça no lugar", o resultado sempre será melhor do que os números mandam fazer. Erros acontecerão em qualquer caso Números servem para justificar decisões, certas ou erradas, de forma real ou não (e só um humano sabe se é real), eles não servem ou não deveriam servir para decidir nada subjetivo e estamos falando de algo essencialmente subjetivo que é o comportamento humano. Números não entram na cabeça das pessoas, números não consideram as não ações (ou considera toda não ação como uma ação deliberada, não separa)

Comment: Notificar os negativadores é algo que é desejável quase unanimemente pela comunidade, mas como não tem números que indiquem que isto é bom não é implementado. Ninguém sabe se é bom ou ruim, apenas temos o desejo subjetivo que isso melhorará a experiência. O grande problema dos números é que as pessoas aplicam uma subjetividade neles e tratam como se fosse objetividade. A correlação encontrada em números nem sempre é real, coincidências existem, ou quando não é coincidência, a correlação pode ser diferente da aparente. E podemos entrar em algo semelhante ao gato de Schrödinger.

Comment: Então, o subjetivo leva a **opiniões** que serão direta ou indiretamente influenciadas e 1) ou só refletirão o entendimento de uma panelinha 10 ou 20 _influencers_ 2) ou só alimentará debates de defesa de opinião. Sejam opiniões sensatas ou não as vertentes são essas. É o classico problema da _revolução dos bichos de George Orwell_.

Comment: Curiosamente George Orwell tem toda sua obra criticando subjetiva e implicitamente o uso de números para definir as coisas :) Não sou totalmente contra números, eles são úteis, por exemplo como moderador temos acesso a muitos números das atividades no site, então podemos saber muito como os usuários se comportam, quando um usuário não gosto de outro, não porque os números disseram isso, eles deram a informação, o humano interpreta que há um bias de uma pessoa em relação a outra através dos números.

Comment: Ótimo exemplo! É uma forma de ver. É uma interpretação subjetiva baseado em dados pseudo-objetivos. Este é exatamente o ponto. É nisso que vão se resumir os números. É onde eu acho que precisamos chegar.

Comment: É frustrante votar como duplicata e a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295584/2541) ser fechada como fora de escopo(já havia 4 votos nesse sentido).